# How to Wait for Handler Thread to finish in Xamarin Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, xamarin, xamarin.android

How to wait for the `handler.PostDelayed` to finish before the function continues?

```
    int num = null;
    public int DoSomething()
    {

            var handler = new Handler();
            handler.PostDelayed(() => StartCapital(), 10);

            handler.PostDelayed(() =>
            {
                    num = StartGain();
            }, 300);

           return num;
     }
```

how to `Wait` for the `StartGain()` Method thread to finish? the method takes sometime to finish and the Function it is in returns null

Comment: why do you call the method from another thread if you want to wait the command has been finished?

Comment: it takes time and I don't want the UI to be hanged

Comment: you will have to create a thread using new runnable and pass it to the handler to make it work in the background, right now you are just adding a delay on that piece of code thats all

Comment: delay is not the problem, problem is the function finishes before returning a integer value, which makes return value null

Comment: @VINNUSAURUS - You can try this `Task.Run(async () => { await StartGain(); }).Wait();`

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a problem in understanding the way Threads work, You create a background thread so that you won't have to block the main thread for some huge process to finish among many other uses,

Like in your case the method `StartGain()`  will be executed on the main thread after a delay of 300ms so if you don't want to wait remove the delay and the handler and run it on the normal flow. If the value that method returns are needs for the further calculations then run it in a separate background thread before continuing.

Comment: if I remove the delay `StartCapital()` function sometime ends after `StartGain()` which causes problem

Comment: I understand so don't move it into a background thread , instead run it on your main thread as it's needed for the flow, it's justifiable delay, you can use a different thread to get that value ahead of time